# How to rechange firstDay properties in FullCalendar by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I want to rechange value of firstDay properties of FullCalendar by jquery when i change view mode month -> week.

**Initial**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ firstDay: 0 })
```

**Change To**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ firstDay: moment().weekday() })
```

But it's not work.

I think it's code will place inside viewRender function, but i don't know how do that?.

Please help me, thanks all so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the firstDay option after initialization like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'firstDay', moment().weekday());
```

This requires version 2.9.0 or higher.

This is the docs page describing the getters and setters for calendar options https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/